# displaying images on the UI from a background thread in blackberry

Tags: multithreading, image, blackberry, user-interface, background

I am looking for a way to display images on my UI from a background thread. This background thread recieves streaming images in the form of byte array. I need to diplay it on my UI
Can anyone help with this please?

I already tried accessing the bitmap field from the background thread but nothing happens

Thanks

```
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(jpegBytes, 0, jpegBytes.length, 1);


        final Bitmap bit = bmp;
        final byte [] jp = jpegBytes;
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {                   
                camView.jpegBytes = jp;
                System.out.println(bit);
                camView.bmpStream.setBitmap(bit);
                //camView.bmpStream.
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the code of what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I managed to find the problem I had an issue with the used of references to my parent class. the above code I have posted in the question works perfect if you have a reference to the main class.

Comment: Yes, UiApplication.getUiApplication() gets the UiApplication object for the currently active UI application context. Quite often this is what you want when displaying from the background. I have explained some of this on my blog if you're interested: http://www.hrbuckley.net/2012/03/blackberrry-singletons-application.html

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change the Main Screen means if you need to add field to Main Screen from the Background thread you need to call

```
invalidate();
```

method to repaint the screen otherwise no change will place in Screen

Ex:

```
 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {                   
                camView.jpegBytes = jp;
                System.out.println(bit);
                camView.bmpStream.setBitmap(bit);
                 invalidate();
                //camView.bmpStream.
            }
    });
```

Comment: is it like some screen.invlaidate?

Comment: Yes http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#invalidate%28%29

Comment: Hi Richard I have tried this but it doesnt work for me...is it really possible to replace your UI components from a background thread? I made some logs in my code and it seems to run throught a the replacing part but the UI doesnt get updated! some help with it pelase?